Launchctl "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error" when targeting system
I'm trying use launchctl run a small program, but have not been able to consistently target system. What appears to be happening is target gui, then target system, try to target system, it'll give this error:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

So I run this, which works
sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/$(id -u) /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.skl.cron.plist

Then I boot out of it
sudo launchctl bootout gui/$(id -u) /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.skl.cron.plist

Then try to bootstrap system, as below, it'll throw the bootstrap failed error.
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.skl.cron.plist

I was only able to target system (with the same set of commands) and have the program to run after some time passed, which almost suggests that launchctl is keeping some kind of cache that prevents developers from targeting system after they've targeted as gui.
This is my plist file, stored in /Library/LaunchDaemons/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.skl.cron</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11</string>
        <string>-m</string>
        <string>sklcron.program</string>
    </array>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HOME</key>
        <string>/Users/ron</string>
    </dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>ron</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/ron/.sklcron/daemon/stdout.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/ron/.sklcron/daemon/stderr.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>

I'd like to target system and I'm currently getting the error. It was working yesterday until I switched service target to today for debugging and have not been able to target system since.

did you find a solution to this. I am having a similar issue.

I don't remember well, but I think it had to do with the commands I was using, eg. bootstrap, bootout, etc. either they were not corrected/deprecated and/or was being used in the wrong order. It's also possible it had to do with the interaction with the user (-u).
I ended up abandoning support macOS support because I remember having other issues with it later on.

For the system domain I used enable and kickstart:
launchctl enable system/org.tuxfamily.chrony
launchctl kickstart system/org.tuxfamily.chrony

To also print the process ID use option '-p':
launchctl enable system/org.tuxfamily.chrony
launchctl kickstart -p system/org.tuxfamily.chrony

Filename is /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.tuxfamily.chrony.plist.
I found this hint helpful.

How does this deal with gut rather than system
